# timerfd won't be ready to read when using epoll

Tags: c, linux, timer, epoll

I'm intending to use epoll to check out timerfd and fire some actions.
Code is blow:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct timespec now;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
    int timerfd;
    timerfd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0);
    struct itimerspec new_value;
    new_value.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    new_value.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
    timerfd_settime(timerfd, 0, &new_value, NULL);
    // uint64_t buff;
    // while(true) {
    //  read(timerfd, &buff, sizeof(uint64_t));
    //  printf("%s\n", "ding");
    // }

    // code above works fine.

    struct epoll_event ev, events[10];
    int epollfd;
    epollfd = epoll_create1(0);
    if (epollfd == -1) {
       perror("epoll_create1");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ev.events = EPOLLIN;
    ev.data.fd = timerfd;

    if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, timerfd, &ev) == -1) {
        perror("epoll_ctl: timerfd");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int num;
    printf("start\n");
    while(true) {
        num = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, 10, -1);
        printf("%d\n", num);
        uint64_t buff;
        read(timerfd, &buff, sizeof(uint64_t));
        printf("%s\n", "ding");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When using timerfd seperately, it works fine. Every second will print "ding". But when adding epoll to observe timerfd, progrom will block at epoll_wait for ever.
I'v tryed using EPOLLET, but noting changed. What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `itimerspec` is not properly initialized, so depending on what particular garbage values it contains, `timerfd_settime()` might fail. To detect that, do error checking:

```
if (timerfd_settime(timerfd, 0, &new_value, NULL) != 0) {
      perror("settime");
      exit(-1);
}
```

Another way to debug this is to run your program under the [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace), program, and you will see which, if any, system calls that fails.

The relevant structs looks like this:

```
struct timespec {
   time_t tv_sec;
   long   tv_nsec;
 };

struct itimerspec {
   struct timespec it_interval;  
   struct timespec it_value;  
};
```

You have to initialize both these members completely, and your program will work reliably:

```
new_value.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
new_value.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
new_value.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
new_value.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted without a comment? This is almost certainly the correct answer. Uninitialized garbage in tv_nsec that's larger than a billion will definitely cause the observed behavior (I just tested), while correctly initializing it will make the code work. Also, adding more code is likely to reshuffle the stack and change the uninitialized values in the timers.

Comment: This answer indeed is the right answer, I'v paid the bounty. But even I use the suggestion to re-write the code, I have no clue why use read without fully initialized still works, anybody can tell me why?

Comment: @reavenisadesk Probably because in that case the variables contained garbage values that was still valid values, while a small change to the code, and the garbage might change and be outside the valid range for `tv_nsec`

Comment: @nos Thanks for answering, I will test more to figure this out.